# How to detect keywords from text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I am trying to make a script in Python to use at work to automate some of my tasks. I have been using the module pyautogui to simulate mouse clicks and keystrokes, and it has been working out great so far!

Right now I am trying to figure out how to automatically feed Python a few lines of text and detect some keywords. The text is going to be in the same place each time I run the script, so I figured I could use pyautogui to select the text I want and copy it to my clipboard. After that, I'd use the module win32clipboard to feed Python the text.

Python ends up just printing whatever is on my clipboard.
What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way?

```
import win32clipboard

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
mytext = input(data)
keywords = ["m1", "M1", "Melding 1"]

if any(keyword in mytext for keyword in keywords):
     print("test")

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input(data)` *displays* `data` and waits for your input (which later becomes the value of `mytext`). Simply remove that line. `data` is your text:

```
if any(keyword in data for keyword in keywords):
     print(keyword)
```

If your keywords *did not have spaces*, you could improve your program to avoid incidental substring matching and to get better performance by splitting the text into tokens and comparing the set of tokens to the set of keywords:

```
keywords = {"m1", "M1", "Melding_1"}
if keywords & set(data.split()):
     print("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace:

```
if any(keyword in mytext for keyword in keywords):
     print("test")
```

with the longer and uglier (but functional!):

```
for word in mytext.split(' '):
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword == word: print word
```

Comment: "Melding 1" would not match the split text because "Melding 1" in the text would be split into two tokens.

Comment: In your example, it's "Melding_1", which would not be split by the space character.  If you're looking for phrases, you will need a more involved approach.

Comment: That's why I say "If your keywords did not have spaces..."

Comment: Thanks, I misread your post as the original.  OP will need to use regex or a search library.  Maybe this one https://pypi.org/project/Whoosh/

Answer (score 1):

You're general problem is you're not parsing your text. It's coming in as one big block. You need to split it up into a word list so each word can be evaluated.

```
...
wordlist = mytext.split()

for trigger in keywords:
   if any(trigger in s for s in wordlist):
      print("HIT!")
...
```

Comment: "Melding 1" would not match the split text because "Melding 1" in the text would be split into two tokens.